# what is the call back URL when I am trying call the Salesforce API from the ASP.Net

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am new to SalesForce and I am trying to call the SalesForce API from the ASP.Net Web Application. I am trying to get some records from the Salesforce in to our Application.

[Connected App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PMNf.jpg)

I am creating the connected App and I am little confused what will be the call back URL, because the asp.net application I am building doesn't have an URL yet. Can we give the Salesforce URL for this.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and errors within your question as text. Linking to images hurts our ability to answer your question, and using images for code or error messages makes searching for similar errors impossible. If you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StefanCrain Thanks for the suggestion, but my question is not about coding but I am just checking on a configuration on Salesforce.